# Studio 3T - SQL - IN expression

Tags: sql, mongodb, studio3t

Is it possible to use SQL **IN** expression in Studio 3T?
I can't seem to get this working:

```
select * from employees
where job IN
(select job
from job where redundant=1
group by job)
```

I get an error:

> Unable to execute SQL statement at cursor
>
> expected expression list (alternatives not supported)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to use 'in' but with exact values only https://studio3t.com/knowledge-base/articles/sql-query/#in

You are trying to use subquery, which is not supported.

You could use inner join https://studio3t.com/knowledge-base/articles/sql-query/#supported-sql-joins, but I guess job.job is not unique, so it will result with duplicates.

Comment: Thank you, I though so. I have ended up using the new $lookup (available from MondoDB from 3.6)